# Built-in display brightness can't be changed and one USB port not working after upgrade to Yosemite (10.10.2) on Macbook Air (early 2014)

Tags: macos, mac, usb, brightness, macbook-air

Started happening right after I upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite.

I tried changing the brightness from the keyboard and from the System Preferences and it doesn't work either way.

The brightness indicator shows up on the screen and updates it's value when I use the keyboard, but the actual brightness doesn't change.

Also, one USB port is not working anymore.

I researched online and I found almost nothing. I did a PRAM reset, repaired disk permissions and none of them helped.

Comment: Is this on the built-in display or an external display?

Comment: Also, does the slider in the Displays panel in System Preferences work? Oh one more thing. You're using the screen brightness keys, not accidentally the keyboard-backlight-adjustment keys, right? Does the on-screen symbol have a circle in the middle of the rays, or does it have a flat bar there instead?

Comment: It's the built in display. And the slider in the Displays panel works. Yes, the brightness keys, not the keyboard brightness (those work).
As I said, I changed the slider from the Displays panel and the brightness doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, the problems were caused by some 3rd party kexts that sneaked in when I used Migration Assistant to get stuff from my Hackintosh to my MacBook Air.

Most likely they conflict with Yosemite since everything worked fine until I upgraded from Mavericks.

**Solution:**

- type [`kextstat | grep -v com.apple`](http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/03/list-all-third-party-kernel-extensions/) in Terminal to see the 3rd party kexts
- use [Kext Wizard](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/253395-kext-wizard-easy-to-use-kext-installer-and-more/) to identify those kexts in `System/Library/Extensions`
- remove those kexts if you're sure you won't be needing them (I renamed them adding a `.bak` suffix)
- reboot